# InvalidArgumentException View [admin.products.view_products] not found. in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

m trying to show database records in admin panel and its showing me error: InvalidArgumentException View [admin.products.view_products] not found. any solution to resolve it??

my function is:

```
public function viewProducts(){
$products = Product::get();
$products = json_decode(json_encode($products));
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($products); die;
return view('admin.products.view_products')->with(compact('products'));
}
```

Route is:

```
  Route::get('/admin/view-products','ProductsController@viewProducts');
```

this is form:

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product ID</th>
          <th>Category ID</th>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Product Code</th>
          <th>Product Color</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach($products as $product)
        <tr class="gradeX">
          <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $product->category_id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $product->product_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $product->product_code }}</td>
          <td>{{ $product->product_color }}</td>
          <td>{{ $product->price }}</td>
          <td class="center"><a href="{{ url('/admin/edit-product/'.$product- 
    >id) }}" class="btn 
   btn-primary btn-mini">Edit</a> <a id="delCat" href="{{ url('/admin/delete- 
  product/'.$product->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: show your view folder structures and where you have stored `view_products.blade.php` file

Comment: your view file must in  `resources/admin/products` named `view_products.blade.php`

Comment: @Sohel0415 here is link of screenshot of folder structure: https://imageshack.com/i/pnsSHilKp

Comment: @innoHaxor just rename your filename to `view_products.blade.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your view file must in

`resources/admin/products directory` named `view_products.blade.php`

controller

```
public function viewProducts(){
    $data['products'] = Product::all();
    return view('admin.products.view_products',$data);
}
```